# What scripts and resources are available for "Air Dropping"?

Tags: airdrops, documentation

Preparing for an "Air Drop" on EOS. What scripts can be used to automate this process?
What relevant documentation, tips and tools are available?

Answer (score 1):

You may try EOSDrops, it is from EOS Essentials (who made Scatter):
https://github.com/EOSEssentials/EOSDrops

Answer (score 1):

For the EOSDAC airdrop we used this -> https://github.com/eosdac/DACtools/tree/master/drop%20tool

It also also a nice verify function to pick up those missed transfers